# Open function in POSIX C not working

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, file-io, posix

I'm trying to get my open function to work with this program, it is reading the input correctly, as I can see if I printf the file name after I type it in, but my open function must be wrong, I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it and it keeps returning -1 and exiting. I am trying to just open a file called tester.txt and I'm using a virtual machine running ubuntu. Any help is appreciated,thanks everyone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

int bytes_read = 1;
int nbytes = 32;
char buffer[32];

char s[] = "name";
printf("Welcome to File Copy by %s!\n", s);


char *inputFile = NULL;
puts("Enter the name of the source file: ");
bytes_read = getline(&inputFile, &nbytes, stdin);
//if fail exit
int inputOpen = open("inputFile", O_RDONLY);    
//if fail exit

if (inputOpen == -1){
    printf("file not found.\n");
    return -1;
}
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: int inputOpen = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY);    inputFile is a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what is entered as the name of the file, you try to open a file called "inputFile". You need to add code to extract the filename from the line entered.

This would be one way:

```
char *eol;


bytes_read = getline(&inputFile, &nbytes, stdin);
eol = strchr(inputFile, '\n');
if (eol != NULL) // remove end of line
    *eol = 0;
int inputOpen = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: When I try to do that method, I get a warning saying that there's an "incompatible implicit declaration of built in function "strchr"

Comment: I included <string> and that fixed the problem but I'm still having the same problem as before, inputOpen keeps returning -1

Comment: @user2739431 Show us the fixed code. I can't debug code I can't see.